# React - GSAP w/ ScrollMagic - Cannot add Scene option 'tweenChanges', because it already exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, gsap

The goals of this [Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/reveal-effect-with-reactjs-and-greensock-3qfx8) (Go to the scrollExample folder whitch is responsible for the /scroll route) is to trigger the image reveal effect on the section scroll.

**How i'm doing the animation:**

First i'm  using the CSSRulePlugin of GSAP to get the pseudo element that i want to animate. 
After that, i created a timeline to put the tween and write the animation properties.

Now talking about ScrollMagic, first i created a Controller and then a Scene. With the scene, i'm passing the element selector that i want to trigger the animation and also the duration (amount of pixels). And the most important part is to set the tween that will get triggered on the section scroll.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        const imageReveal = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".image-container:after");
        const timeline = new TimelineLite();
        timeline.from(imageReveal, {
          duration: 0.4,
          cssRule: { scale: 1.2 }
        });

        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: "#scrollStarts",
          duration: 100
        })
          .setTween(timeline)
          .addTo(this.controller); // assign the scene to the controller
      }
```

**The problem:**
The scroll animation is not working and i'm getting the following errors:

```
[static] ScrollMagic.Scene -> Cannot add Scene option 'tweenChanges', because it already exists.
(animation.gsap) -> ERROR calling method 'setTween()': Supplied argument is not a valid TweenObject
```

I don't why my tween is invalid and why the tweenChanges already exists since i didn't see anything happening on the scroll.

Comment: change the class name it happened, because of you could use this class another component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two libraries are being used in the project — [`scrollmagic-plugin-gsap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollmagic-plugin-gsap) and the default one in [`scrollmagic`](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/master/dev/src/plugins/animation.gsap.js).

`scrollmagic-plugin-gsap` is meant to be configured with `ScrollMagic`, `TweenMax`, `TimelineMax`, not `ScrollMagic` and `gsap`. Refer to [usage docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollmagic-plugin-gsap#usage)

Looking closely, `scrollmagic-plugin-gsap` isn't required in your project as you can roll with the plugin provided in `scrollmagic` library.

As `animation.gsap.js` from `scrollmagic` library is imported already in `App`, uninstall `scrollmagic-plugin-gsap` and remove from `scrollExample` these lines:

```
import { ScrollMagicPluginGsap } from "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap";

ScrollMagicPluginGsap(ScrollMagic, gsap);
```

The error in the console should go away. The error was logged because the plugin in `scrollmagic-plugin-gsap` and the one rolled in `scrollmagic` both add `tweenChanges` option.